# I have two ArrayList A & B , Just i wanted to find whether the elements in array A is existing in array B element

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists A & B , I just wanted to find whether the elements in ArrayList A are existing in ArrayList B elements.

I just tried this.

`if(ArrayListA.contains(ArrayListB))`

Lets consider :

if `ArrayListA = {1,2};` and if `ArrayListB = {2};` it must return **false**.

if `ArrayListA = {1,2};` and if `ArrayListB = {2,1};` it must return **true**.

But in vain , can any one help me out?

Comment: You need to check how many elements exist in both the list ?

Comment: It would be easier to understand your problem with a working code sample. Please post your code as an [minimal, complete, tested and readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: i have updated my question with snippet of code.

Comment: @Uday The 'containsAll' (as opposed to 'contains') method tests exactly what you want to test in your pseudocode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are checking if your list A contains your list B (as an object) as opposed to checking if your list A contains all of the elements of your list B.

Use the [`containsAll(Collection<?>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method instead:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();

a.add("a");
a.add("b");
a.add("c");

b.add("a");
b.add("c");

System.out.println("b is a subset of a: " + a.containsAll(b));

System.out.println("a is a subset of b: " + b.containsAll(a));
```

Comment: This would be the method I also suggest, kudos +1 from my end!!

Comment: Thanks for the clean explanation.so + 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
for(int i = 0; i< ArrayListB.size(); i++){
      if(ArrayListA.contains(ArrayListB.get(i)){
           System.out.print("Found");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (arrayListB.containsAll(arrayListA))
```

Comment: This would only work if `arrayListB` contains, as a single entry, the entire `arrayListA`.

Comment: This just checks whether one element of arrayListB equals arrayListA.

Comment: Right, my fault, fixed

Comment: Yeah he is right, this will work perfect.
Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to convert the two ArrayLists to Set objects then use set operations to determine if one is a subset of another. This will also avoid duplicity:

```
ArrayList<String> a1 = ...;
ArrayList<String> a2 = ...;

public boolean isSubset(ArrayList<String> a1, ArrayList<String> a2) {

     Set<String> s1 = new HashSet(a1);
     Set<String> s2 = new HashSet(a2);

     return s1.containsAll(s2);
     }
```